# manage.py runserver with Django on Jython

Tags: python, django, jython

Can I run Django's internal server for testing with Jython?

I've installed django-jython, but I get this message when I try to run the server:

```
jython manage.py runserver 8000

Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_manager 
ImportError: No module named django
```

Comment: What version of Jython ? In which directory is Django-jython installed ?

Comment: It's ok it contains "/Users/cassiomelo/code/jython/Lib/site-packages" where "django_jython-1.3.0b2-py2.5.egg-info" is

Comment: @jpic : 1.3.0b2 and /Users/cassiomelo/code/jython/Lib/site-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that Jython **cannot find the 'django' module**. Here, the first thing Jython is going to do is try to find the django module:

```
from django.core.management import execute_manager
```

It fails, and throws `ImportError: No module named django`.

You should find out **where your django module is**, it should be a directory named 'django' that contains an `__init__.py` file.

[Set your python path for jython](http://stefaanlippens.net/jython_and_pythonpath) to the parent directory. For example, if you find `/Users/cassiomelo/code/jython/Lib/site-packages/django/__init__.py`, then you should add `/Users/cassiomelo/code/jython/Lib/site-packages` to the python path. Click the link to see how to set it depending on **your Jython version**.

The next time Jython will try to import the 'django' module, it will look in the directory of the python path if there is a directory named 'django' with an `__init__.py` in it and **proceed to importing the core submodule**, then management, then execute_manager.